# Easiest way to store JSON files online?

Tags: node.js, json, persistent-storage

I have an app deployed on Heroku which relies on persistent information. Since the data is simple enough, I thought the best way to store it would be to read and write a JSON file in the system. However, Heroku resets its dynos every now and then which resets my JSON file back to its original state. I tried to look for services online which store JSON files and found none. I didn't want to use MongoDB, Firebase, or anything similar since those are pretty overkill for the data that I want to store. What would be the easiest way to persist data in this case?

For additional information, the JSON file's layout is simply the following which is why I thought using full-fledged databases were overkill.

```
{
  "count": Number,
  "retrieved": [

  ]
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't want to use MongoDB? How is that overkill?

Comment: @Proximo since I only ever need to store one object, and not necessarily an entire collection of them, I figured if there's an easier way to persist then I'd go with that. But by the looks of things, looks like there's none

Comment: This question is pretty old and may be you must have figured out a solution for the above. But just to help the users who might visit this question going forward, you could use services like https://jsonbin.io to store JSON with ease without any learning curve. p.s I am the author of JSONBin.io

Comment: Have you tried Cloud Pantry? https://getpantry.cloud/

Answer (score 1):

I know you said a fully fledged database such as MongoDB would be overkill, but, I highly recommend reconsidering this. An alternative would be some sort of file storage website and while this wouldn't be a "fully fledged database", it would not make things simpler for you as you would need to consider all the extra steps and hacky methods to emulate a database, so in the end you may as well just use a database to avoid these hurdles.

And don't forget once you are set up, you can use MongoDB Atlas (a cloud solution for MongoDB) for many other projects in the future quite easily without going through a lot of the initial set up. Another thing to consider is expandability of your current project, you never know what great ideas you may come up with or what aspects you have not yet considered come up.

Comment: I'm already considering but looks like I have no other options. I'll look further into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**use localtorage**
example

```
var data = {
  "count": Number,
  "retrieved": [

  ]
}
```

**to set**

```
localStorage.setItem('_d', JSON.stringify(data));

var restoredSession = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_d')); 

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
```

Comment: I'm hosting the app on heroku and I'd need it to be accessible online, not just on my browser

Comment: I'm afraid you should use a database